# R.java is missing, what are other possible errors that led to this?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

R.java in gen is missing. There are no errors in my xml. Please help.

Comment: step 1 - Clean and build.. then come back...

Comment: When I clean the project, build cannot be clicked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **Restart** the Eclipse will solve this Issue as the workspace will be freshly Build  ! go to

**File -> Restart**

Its the fastest way to avoid frustration by going it into Build,preferencen,blah blah.....

Comment: Many, many, many times, this WON'T WORK.

Comment: But It have worked for me everytime especially whenever i delete R.java & if it is not regenerated automatically

Comment: In most cases, for me it didn't work, since there always was some well hidden bug in some xml files (sometimes, in strings.xml, in someone of the languages I support)

Comment: When I add this appcompat library to the project, the R.java disappears, but when I unable this library, R.java appears..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clean and build your project. try